# How to publish automatically a value from one view to another in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Currently, I have one view with a date picker that sets a preferred time. I have a UserData file that stores the preferred time in a user defaults, and finally, I have a second view that displays that preferred time as a string.

Here is my problem: the preferred time is properly set in user default, but isnt automatically reflected in the second view. When I tap "Back" the displayed time does not change. However, when I quit the app and come back, the new time is reflected.

How can I automatically sync both of these views?

View 1 (with datepicker):

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct SettingsDetailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userData = UserData()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            //MARK - FORM
            Form{
                
                DatePicker("Select a new time", selection: $userData.wakeUpTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View 2 (where preferred time should be displayed automatically)

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct SettingsView: View {

    @ObservedObject var userData = UserData()
        
    static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
            return formatter
        }()

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                Form{
                    Section(header: Text("NOTIFICATION SETTINGS")) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Current Notification Time")
                            .foregroundColor(Color("MainText"))
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text("\(self.userData.wakeUpTime, formatter: SettingsView.self.dateFormatter)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And UserData:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class UserData: ObservableObject {

@Published var wakeUpTime: Date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "wakeUpTime") as? Date ?? Date() {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.wakeUpTime, forKey: "wakeUpTime")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating 2 UserData() object. Instead of creating new object in details view, you need to pass user data object to the details screen

Comment: @RajaKishan I'm also curious about this, yes he/she is creating 2 UserData() objects, but since its a class isn't it using the same instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how your views joined together. If `SettingsDetailView` is shown from `SettingsDetailView` then you should pass user data via constructor, like

```
struct SettingsDetailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userData: UserData    // << declared to be injected
// ...
}
```

and somewhere inside

```
struct SettingsView: View {

    @ObservedObject var userData = UserData()
        
    static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
            return formatter
        }()

    var body: some View {
        
     // ... 

       SettingsDetailView(userData: self.userData)

     // ...
   }
}
```